# Set Linux command alias for complex query

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

For testing purpose, I need to set up Linux command alias like this:

```
alias 'dmidecode -t 1'='cat ~/test/system_info'
```

But the alias command doesn't work like this. It seems that the alias name should be continuous characters without space. Any thought on how to achieve this? Thanks a lot and really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a `dmidecode()` function that defers to the regular `dmidecode` if its arguments aren't exactly `-t 1`. `command` suppresses function lookup.

```
dmidecode() {
    if [[ $1 == -t && $2 == 1 ]]; then
        cat ~/test/system_info
    else
        command dmidecode "$@"
    fi
}
```